# Arranging nested objects in MS Publisher 2010

Tags: microsoft-publisher

In MS Publisher 2010, how can I align objects that are inside another object respectively?

For example, I want to align two pictures that are inside a textbox in a way that both will be 1cm from the textbox's margins, one in the left and one in the right.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know you can't do that. What I would do in your place is checking the coordinates of the image (bottom left, click on it and you will have the dimension window for your particular object) and than add the amount you want in comparison with your textbox. Publisher isn't InDesign...
[image: dimension published windows]